# how to send a image and data from client to nodejs server with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using reactjs and sending an image and data associated with it in a form.

```
 <form>
<input type='file' name='image'/>
</form>

let formdata = new formData();
formdata.append('file',file);
formdata.append(data,data);
let output = axios({
methodname=post,
path = '/image',
header = {
       auth : token,
       content-type: multipart/form-data
         },
data : formdata
})

formdata = { file: (file)
             data:{
                title:'',
                desc:''
                  }
}
```

**and now on the server side**

```
let upload = multer({dest:'./pictures'});

router.post('/image',verifytoken,upload.single('image'),functions(req,res){
console.log(req.file); ?????
});
```

I think the way of sending the file is a problem but I am not able to find the structure of the request coming from client axios. Every advice and suggestions are welcome

**Error: unexpected token**

```
 createImage(data) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', data.file);
    formData.append('data', data.data);
    let axiosObject = {
      methodName: 'post',
      path: '/image',
      data: formData,
      header: {
        authorization: null,
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }
    let result = this.axiosManager(axiosObject);
    return result;
  }


 axiosManager(axiosObject) {
    let authorizationToken = this.getAuthorizationToken();
    axiosObject.header.authorization = authorizationToken;

    let output = axios({
      method: axiosObject.methodName,
      url: config.apiServer + axiosObject.path,
      data: axiosObject.data,
      headers: axiosObject.header
    });

    return output.then((httpResponse) => {
      if (httpResponse.data.success === true) {
        return httpResponse.data.data;
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(httpResponse.data.error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(formData)` in the request data then in node server `console.log(req.data.file)`

Comment: i got an error as 'multipart:bounday not found'

Comment: try removing `content-type: multipart/form-data` replace it with `content-type: application/json`

Comment: i changed content type but in server route i got console.log(req.file) as undefined

Comment: `console.log(req.body.file)` .?? wats the output

Comment: req.body is empty object and req.file is undefined

Comment: i just updated my code with the actual function what i have and axios manager and data = {data: {title:'',desc:''}, file: File(104405)}

Comment: Do you have to use axios?

Comment: yes i have to use axios

Comment: does a simple `axios.post('/image', { data: formData })` not work?

Comment: No it did not work. Solution of this is i am  sending the file as    formData.append('file', data.file); instead i have ti send it like   formData.append('image', data.file);. for getting values on server as req.body . i have to append the title and desc seperately like (   formData.append('title', data.data.title); &   formData.append('desc', data.data.desc);)